# C# classes communication design question

Tags: c#, events, class, communication

I have a design questions about this scenario:
Suppose you have a **form with many sites to be filled**, let's call each site a plugin.
Among other classes I've created a `PluginManager` class that takes evidence of all plugins and provides some functionality and properties:

```
class PluginManager
{
  ...
  BasePlugin CurrentPlugin {get;set;}
  IEnumerable<BasePlugin> OpenedPlugins {}
  bool SetPlugin() {..}
  ...
}

class BasePlugin {}
class MyPlugin : BasePlugin {}
```

Among other thins, it handles **displaying the chosen plugin / site**.

Until now I never needed to communicate between 2 or more plugins. Now I do and I wanted to ask you, how would you do that.

My opinion was to add en `Event` to the `BasePlugin` class and handle it in `PluginsManager` class, in some way, that the Plugin raising the `Event` would provide in the `EventArgs` the types of all other Plugins that should be affected and a list of `delegates` pointing at the methods that should be executed.

Do you have any idea? Thank you !

Comment: What kind of communication?  A simple method call, complex messaging, etc?

Comment: Let's say a simple method call !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Chain Of Responsibility" Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). The plug-in calls the manager to get some information from *anywhere*. The manager asks each plug-in to put the information into a provided interface. (What is a kind of a [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)).

Greets
Flo

Comment: I suggested the Mediator pattern, which is a 'push' method (plug-in would broadcast information), while you have suggested Chain of Responsability as a 'pull' method, which I woudn't have thought of!  +1 for you.

Comment: @Dr Herbie: and +1 for you for another nice idea :-). As you already mentioned, it always depends.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a possible [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) to me (see also [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx) for a description with C# code).

A mediator class handles communications between other classes.  Your `PlugInManager` class would have a private `Mediator` instance and all the plug-ins would register with the mediator to receive communications.

There are probably 101 ways to do this, so expect a variety of answers.